# Pocket API authorization loop

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, php

Setting up a plugin using Pocket API and I'm currently in a authorization loop.

Index template calls the init function. Init function gets requestToken (successfully) and then redirects to Pocket for app authorization (authorizeToken function). After authorization, redirected to callback.

From here, I need to convert the token to a 'Pocket access token', but when the controlller fires it seems to call the init function before the accessToken function and I end up in an endless loop.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Am I going about this the right way?

**Index template:**

```
{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}
{% set title = "Pocket Articles"|t %}

{% set offset = craft.request.getParam('offset') %}
{% set start = craft.pocket.init() %}

{% set content %}
    {{ start }}
{% endset %}
```

**Service:**

```
public function init(){
    $token  = $this->requestToken();
    $auth   = $this->authorizeToken($token);
    return;
}

public function accessToken($code){
    $url                    = $this->getSetting('access_path'); //https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/authorize
    $requirements['code']   = $code;
    $requirements['key']    = $this->getSetting('consumer_key');

    $curl = $this->initCurl($url, $requirements);
    $results = curl_exec($curl);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);
    echo "</pre>";

    curl_close($curl);

    return $results;
}

private function authorizeToken($token){
    $auth_path      =$this->getSetting('auth_path'); //https://getpocket.com/auth/authorize?
    $redirect_path  =$this->getSetting('callback_path');
    $actionUrl = UrlHelper::getActionUrl('pocket/callback');


    $url = $auth_path.'request_token='.$token.'&redirect_uri='.$actionUrl;

    header("Location:".$url);

    return $url;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function actionCallback(){

    //call pocket server for acccess token
    if(craft()->httpSession->get('code')){
        $code   = craft()->httpSession->get('code');
    }else{
        $code   = "no code";
    }

    $access_connection = craft()->pocket->accessToken($code);
    $variables['access_token'] = $access_connection;

    $this->renderTemplate('pocket/control_panel', $variables);


}
```

**Callback template:**

```
{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}
{% set title = "Pocket Articles"|t %}

{% set offset = craft.request.getParam('offset') %}

{% set content %}
    {{ dump(access_token) }}
{% endset %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `init` method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplicationComponent#init-detail) is automatically called whenever a service class is instantiated. Think of it as akin to a constructor.

If this is not want you want, just rename the method (to `initialize`, for example).

Comment: I should add that to my bio.